# Can't access Heroku variables with PHP

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php, environment-variables

I'm using `.env` file as database connection variables. I can't share `.env` file on GitHub, so I need to use Heroku variables config (I set them as local `.env` file). But when I call `getenv('VAR_NAME')` I get

> Unable to read any of the environment file(s)

because there are not any `.env` file. How can I access Heroku variables using PHP?

**Edit:** I'm using this package: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Here is my code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use PDO;
use Dotenv\Dotenv as Dotenv;
public function getConnection()
        {
            $this->db_connection = null;
            try
            {
                $dotenv = Dotenv::create(__DIR__ . '/..');
                $dotenv->load();
                $this->db_connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . getenv('DB_HOST') . ";dbname=" . getenv('DB_DATABASE'), getenv('DB_USERNAME'), getenv('DB_PASSWORD'));
                $this->db_connection->exec("set names utf8");
            }
            catch(PDOException $exception)
            {
                echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
            }
            return $this->db_connection;
        }
```

`__DIR__ . '/..'` is localization of `.env` file

Laravel framework has `.env` file as well, but it has post-script that creates `.env` file if it doesn't exist:

```
(composer.json)
"scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
}
```

When I stopped using Dotenv class it started working.

Comment: PHP's standard [`getenv()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) doesn't have anything to do with `.env` files. It gets a variable from the _environment_. Some tools populate the environment _from_ `.env` files, but `getenv()` itself doesn't look at those files. But the error you quote specifically talks about environment _files_, which means you're not using the standard `getenv()`. Please [edit] your question and clarify it. Ideally, we'd like a [mcve].

Comment: Also, what does "I set them as local `.env` file" mean, and what does that have to do with Heroku's config vars?

Comment: Please show how you initialize `Dotenv`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure there is no .env file on heroku, all the variables that are added to config will be available as environment variables. So i would suggest same method as Chris suggested.

```
<?php
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/.env')) {
    $dotenv = Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
    $dotenv->load();
}
```

Check if environment is not production/staging or .env file exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

`vlucas/phpdotenv` throws an exception if you try to initialize it and it can't find an appropriate `.env` file. This [was discussed](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/84) and the author ultimately decided not to change this behaviour. Two workarounds are discussed in that issue, both of which work:

1. Only initialize Dotenv if a file can be found, e.g. something like

   ```
   <?php
   use Dotenv\Dotenv;

   if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/.env')) {
       $dotenv = Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
       $dotenv->load();
   }
   ```
2. Catch the exception, e.g.

   ```
   <?php
   use Dotenv\Dotenv;
   use Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException;

   try {
       $dotenv = Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
       $dotenv->load();
   } catch (InvalidPathException $e) {
       // Do something
   }
   ```

Personally, I'd prefer the library to handle this gracefully out of the box, but failing that I prefer option 1 above.